# check whether any number in one array is less than some number in the other array

Tags: ruby

This seems like a pretty common question. Sadly I could not find it on SO. If this is a duplicate question; I apologize for that.

Say I have two integer arrays `A` and `B`:

```
A = [17, 3, 9, 11, 11, 15, 2]
B = [1, 13]
```

I need to return a true or a false if any element of array `A` is less than any element of array `B`.

The trivial way to do this was use 2 each loops (`O(n^2)` complexity)

```
def is_greater?(a,b)
  retVal = false
  b.each { |element|
    a.each { |value|
      if (value < element)
        retVal = true
        break
      end
    }
  }
  return retVal
end

is_greater?(A,B) => true
```

I also sorted out the elements in both the arrays and then used a single while loop to determine whether the element in `A` is less than that in `B`.

```
A.sort!
B.sort!
def is_greater?(a,b)
  retVal = false
  i = 0
  j = 0
  while (i < a.length && j < b.length)
    if (a[i] < b[j])
      retVal = true
      break
    elsif (a[i] == b[j])
      i = i + 1
      j = j + 1
    else
     j = j + 1
    end
  end
  return retVal
end

is_greater?(A,B) => true
```

I was wondering whether there is an efficient, precise way to do it in terms of lines of code. I was trying to figure out how to use the `any?` block, but it did not make any sense to me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can use Enumerable methods #any? and #min

For each item in a, return true if it is less than max:

```
max = b.max
a.any?{|x| x < max}
```

Comment: thanks! i used this solution with the max value storing advice given by @TCopple

Answer (score 5):

It should be enough to just check the minimum of the first array against the maximum of the second.

```
a.min < b.max
```

The only way this conditional returns false is if every element is `b` is less than every element in `a`.

The complexity is O(m+n) which is the single iteration through both `a` and `b`.

Comment: atleast its linear rather than O(nlogn) and O(n^2) solutions which I proposed. Thanks for the max value caching tip

Comment: It is actually `O(2n) = O(n)` (Product rule with constant) when `m ~= n`, not `O(n logn)`. It is the same as the other solution.

Comment: @texasbruce I don't know if you're talking about my solution, but if you are I agree it reduces to the same complexity as the other answer. But.... m = len(a) and n = len(b), which is not O(2n) cause n can only represent the length of one array.

Comment: @texasbruce The O(n logn) was the complexity of the sorting solution which I gave, TCopple's solution has the complexity O(m+n).. essentially its linear

Comment: @TCopple well the problem is that any element and not every element is required to be less than

Comment: Yeah that's why I said m ~= n, meaning approximately equal, and yes it is linear.

Comment: The algorithm complexity is O(m+n). O(m+n) = O(2n) = O(n) if and only if m = n